# How to get the node name for a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What is the `kubectl` command that retrieves only the node name for a given pod? I'm aware that `kubectl get pods <my-pod> -o wide` would display this information, but what I want is the `kubectl` command that only displays the node name, so I can use it as a shell script variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below commands

```
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox:1.28 --command -- sleep 3600

POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -l run=busybox -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
NODE_NAME=$(kubectl get pod $POD_NAME -o "jsonpath={.spec.nodeName}")
echo $NODE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
NODE=$(kubectl get pod -n <my-namespace> <my-pod> -o "jsonpath={.spec.nodeName}")
```